# Laravel class not found with one-to-many

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to return an object `Contract` and all of it's related `Project`. I can return all of the `Contract`s but when I try to get the contract's `Project`, I get a "Class 'EstimateProject' not found" error. I've run `composer dump-autoload` to reload the class mappings, but I still get the error. Any ideas? Here's my class setup:

**EDIT:** Just wanted to add that `LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent\` is an extension of Laravel's Model.php. It adds validation to model on the `Save` function. I've made Ardent extend another plugin I've added that is a MongoDB version of the Eloquent ORM.

**EstimateContract.php**

```
<?php namespace Test\Tools;

  use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;

  class EstimateContract extends Ardent {

     // This sets the value on the Mongodb plugin's '$collection'
     protected $collection = 'Contracts';

     public function projects()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('EstimateProject', 'contractId');
     }
  }
```

**EstimateProject.php**

```
<?php namespace Test\Tools;

  use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;

  class EstimateProject extends Ardent {

   // This sets the value on the Mongodb plugin's '$collection'
   protected $collection = 'Projects';

   public function contract()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('EstimateContract', 'contractId');
   }
}
```

**EstimateContractController.php**

```
<?php

  use  \Test\Tools\EstimateContract;

  class EstimateContractsController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
    public function index()
    {
        $contracts = EstimateContract::all();

        echo $contracts;

        foreach($contracts as $contract)
        {
            if($contract->projects)
            {
                echo $contract->projects;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: try putting `use  \Test\Tools\EstimateProject;` in `EstimateContractController.php`

Comment: @TryingTobemyself unfortunately, I already tried that to no avail.

Comment: try putting `use \Test\Tools\EstimateProject;` in `EstimateContract.php`

Comment: @TryingTobemyself Also tried that.

Comment: does `$projects = EstimateProject::all();` works?

Comment: Yes, I think I figured out my problem though. I added the fully qualified path to the ZEstimateProject is the `projects()` function in ZEstimateContract and it seems to work (although I'm not actually getting any projects back yet). So, I changed it from `return $this->hasMany('EstimateProject', 'contractId');`   to   `return $this->hasMany('\Test\Tools\EstimateProject', 'contractId');`

Comment: good...so is it working now? And instead of using foreach you can use this `$contracts = EstimateContract::with('EstimateProject')->all();`

Comment: It's sort of working (i.e. it doesn't break). I'm just not getting back results for the projects. Also, I tried the Eager Loading approach but it keeps failing saying there's a call to the undefined method `project()`. I think this is because Eager Loading isn't supported in my MongoDB plugin I'm using

Comment: Scratch that, it's because I was typing in the method name incorrectly. `return EstimateContract::with('projects')->get();` works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order for this to work, I needed to fully qualify the EstimateProject string in my EstimateContract model.

The solution was to change it from:

```
return $this->hasMany('EstimateProject', 'contractId');
```

to

```
return $this->hasMany('\Test\Tools\EstimateProject', 'contractId');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the fully qualified name, but I got the same error when I used forward slashes instead of back slashes:

```
//Correct
return $this->hasMany('Fully\Qualified\ClassName');
//Incorrect
return $this->hasMany('Fully/Qualified/ClassName');
```